# c++ list allocate irregular memory

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, malloc

How to resolve list memory problem?
Data.h

```
    class Data {
        public: static Data * instance ;    
        private: 
            list<int> preVar;
            static Data * createData() ;
    };
```

Data.cpp

```
Data * Data::instance = Data::createData();
Data::Data() { }

    Data * Data::createData(){                  
        Data * tmp = (Data*)malloc(sizeof(Data));
        tmp->preVar.clear();     // ERROR
        return tmp;
    }
```

Debug point is (error) int list.tcc :  __cur = static_cast<_Node*>(__cur->_M_next);

Comment: What made you think you can create objects with malloc like that?

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` does not construct objects, it simply allocates memory, thus `preVar` object is not fully constructed, accessing it invoke undefined behavior.

**Always use `new` in C++!!!**